# socket.io nodejs app hosted on openshift - scaling

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

I have nodejs app based on web sockets (socket.io) and I decided to host this app on openshift. And when I want to create new app on openshift I have no idea if should I set scaling turn on or turn off.

Does anyone could help me with this. Because I think when is my app based on web sockets scaling is useless. Thanks for any information

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, a gear is limited to 16 concurrent connections (including websocket). If you expect more connections, yes you should allow your application to scale.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I tried right now connect more than 20 clients (websockets) without scale and everything is working fine It means gear is not limited to 16 connections (including websockets)

Comment: OK, thanks for the information.